# Upgrade Laravel to 5.4 from 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-upgrade

My project is working on `5.3` laravel version and trying to upgrade it.

I have updated `composer.json` as guided into the documentation of laravel guide.
And run command `composer update` on command line.

I am getting following error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.35
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.34
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.32
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.31
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.30
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.29
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.27
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.24
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.23
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
- cartalyst/stripe-laravel v5.0.1 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.31], illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- cartalyst/stripe-laravel v5.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.31], illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- cartalyst/stripe-laravel v5.0.1 requires illuminate/support 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.31], illuminate/support[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.3.31].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].
- Installation request for cartalyst/stripe-laravel 5.0.* -> satisfiable by cartalyst/stripe-laravel[v5.0.0, v5.0.1].
```

This is `composer.json`

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "sly/notification-pusher": "^2.2",
    "baum/baum": "^1.1",

    "rtconner/laravel-tagging": "^2.0",
    "michele-angioni/laravel-js-lang-converter": "^2.1",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "eluceo/ical": "^0.9.0",
    "twilio/sdk": "^4.10",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.9.3",
    "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "5.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models",
      "app/Console/Commands"

    ],
    "files": [
      "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's issue because some of your package version is not supporting new
>   laravel version 5.4

For example

```
"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "5.0.*"
```

cartalyst/stripe-laravel version 5.0.1 only compatible with laravel 5.3 or lower so it's not support your new laravel.

Now you have two method to update your laravel

1. you can remove  "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "5.0.*" from your package json and just add like composer require  cartalyst/stripe-laravel this command add your compatible version in your system
2. or just find manually compatible version of cartalyst/stripe-laravel and replace in your package json form here [cartakyst.stripe-laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/cartalyst/stripe-laravel#v7.0.0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think `"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "6.0.*"` is solved my issue! Right?

Comment: You can check 'Laravel Compatibility' block on given url  6.0.x is for 5.4 and 
7.0.x is for 5.5

Comment: Yes, thanks. Let me try `"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "6.0.*"` and then let you know if it works!

Comment: Gives me this error: `[RuntimeException]                                                                            
  Could not delete /var/www/html/laravel-project/vendor/psy/psysh/test/fixtures/config.php:`

Comment: you permission to vendor folder or rename vendor vendor_old and try again composer update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158662/discussion-between-bipin-patel-and-hiren-gohel).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue! :)